# How to use CountDownLatch/Synchronized on an object that is being accessed by multiple threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, jax-ws

I received a legacy JAX-WS code, which I found out is not thread safe. Therefore I want to implement a CountDownLatch on an object that is being accessed by multiple threads at the same time. 
I cannot put up the entire code here, so I will simplify the code referring to the object I want to use a CountDownLatch on,

```
public class JAXDataLoader extends ClassFoo implements Executor{
  private static ClassBar mInstance = null;
  public JAXDataLoader(ClassBar instance) {
    super();
    mInstance = instance;
  }
}
```

This `mInstance` object is an important object for my JAX-WS client as I get my URL address and port from this class, i.e.,

```
URL address = mInstance.getConnectionEndpoint(); //returns example: http://10.11.800.111:5019
```

Basically what I need to do is something like,

```
synchronized(instance){
    mInstance = instance;
}
```

But this doesn't really work! Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: You should synchronize on some inner object, not a method argument, as it may be different in different invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize when you make your mInstance.getConnectionEndpoint() calls.   A nice way to do it is to make a wrapper class and synchronize that class.  Not sure you want to implement Executor?

```
public final class ClassBarWrapper{
  private final ClassBar mInstance;
  public ClassBarWrapper(ClassBar instance){
    this.mInstance=instance;
  }
  public URL synchronize getConnectionEndpoint(){
    return mInstance.getConnectionEndpoint();
  }
}
```